# A cheaper alternative to ManicTime (time tracking) with no online features

Tags: windows, project-management, productivity

[ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is great software but it appears to me as quite costly for what it does ($70). I would gladly buy it if it was cheaper but as it stands, it's too much.

What I like the most is the day by day tab. I'm not that much interested in the weekly report or timesheet.

I'm sorry but there are a lot of alternatives so I'm not sure which to chose.

What I want is :

- same features as ManicTime for day to day management (tags,
  stopwatch, timeline, applications used, documents used,
  active/inactive detection, auto tagging..)
- absolutely NO server-side logs, my data is my company property I don't want it being tracked online
- free or less than $30

Comment: ManicTime itself has a free version and I think that would suffice your requirements. One of the features NOT available on the free version is precisely the online thing (which they call "ManicTime Server"). Look here:  http://www.manictime.com/pricing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, another very very good option (and totally free) is [ProcrastiTracker](https://strlen.com/procrastitracker/) which is now open source!

The last time I checked it wasn't open source, so great to see it out on GitHub.  Kudos to Wouter van Oortmerssen (who seems to work at Google currently) for making it and setting it free under the Apache v2 license!

Procrastitracker is solid, dependable and very useful in my experience. ManicTime is definitely slicker and has more features.  But Procrastictracker comes in a close second for me, and if you factor in the free and open part, that makes it an awesome option.

I have used both of them for several years to account ($) for my time!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/).

> RescueTime gives you an accurate picture of how you spend your time to help you become more productive every day.
>
> Detailed reports show which applications and websites you spent time on. Additional reports show how much time you spent in different categories, how productive you were, and whether you achieved your goals.

The paid version is $7 a month, but there is a free version which I think covers your needs.